# I have a problem with adding padding to a container-fluid. I tried using Bootstrap 4.0.0 and 4.4.1 but it won't add the padding

Tags: css

I have a problem with adding padding to a container-fluid. I tried using Bootstrap 4.0.0 and 4.4.1 but it won't add the padding. My code looks the same as my instructor who's using bootstrap 4.0.0

I tried using the same version it didn't work and I tried using the latest version still didn't work.

```css
/*css*/

.container-fluid {
  padding: 3% 15%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="title">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h1 class="hTitle">Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
        <button type="button">Download</button>
        <button type="button">Download</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: How do you apply your bootstrap and style files?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @SMAKSS hey, I copied the BootstrapCDN from their website and added it to the head of my boilerplate. As far of the style file, I added the link tag in the head of my boilerplate as well, I can confirm that the style file is properly linked to my HTML file.

Comment: Which one comes first? Bootstrap or your stylesheet?

Comment: @SMAKSS I had the stylesheet first, problem fixed thank you so much.